# google pie chart loading after ajax loads

Tags: php, jquery, api, pie-chart

I've been using the google pie chart and jquery Ajax.Load()

My problem is the pie chart loads only after the ajax load calls return, which is quite missing the point, of letting the page load(including the chart), and then async loading of heavy content.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart.html

The pie chart is loaded by:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

and the Ajax calls are like:

```
$("#id").load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    alert(xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
  else {
      $("#id").show(); 
  }
});
```

how could i make the google pie chart loading happen before the ajax loads finish?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you execute the below code in drawChart method which is actually a callback method for drawing charts

```
$("#id").load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    alert(xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
  else {
      $("#id").show(); 
  }
});
```

Comment: that is creative. but will make a lot of mess in the code, since there are many ajax calls, and seems like there must be a more logical approach to solve this, don't u think?

Comment: The other way is to keep a global variable, set this variable in the drawchart method. Now in ajax call success keep looking for this variable at a certain interval and act on it.

Comment: maybe you can explain why it happens? when is google.SetOnLoadCallback supposed to happen? can't i execute it differetnly so it'll be executed before the ajax loads?